# facebook login in react native app not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook-login

I'm using magus/react-native-facebook-login for my react native app. (Android)

This is my first time developing an app, so needless to say, this is my first time trying to add facebook login feature.

I read all the README, and examples but I still have trouble figuring out how exactly it works.

what I did so far is copy and paste an example code as below :

```
var TestProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
     var _this = this;
     return (
       permissions={["email","user_friends"]}
       loginBehavior={FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Native}
       onLogin={function(data){
         console.log("Logged in!");
         console.log(data);
         _this.setState({ user : data.credentials });
       }}
       onLogout={function(){
         console.log("Logged out.");
         _this.setState({ user : null });
       }}
       onLoginFound={function(data){
         console.log("Existing login found.");
         console.log(data);
         _this.setState({ user : data.credentials });
       }}
       onLoginNotFound={function(){
         console.log("No user logged in.");
         _this.setState({ user : null });
       }}
       onError={function(data){
         console.log("ERROR");
         console.log(data);
       }}
       onCancel={function(){
         console.log("User cancelled.");
       }}
       onPermissionsMissing={function(data){
         console.log("Check permissions!");
         console.log(data);
       }}
       />
     );
   }
 });
```

If I render with the above code, I get "Not Logged in You are not logged in. Please login and try again."

Can anybody tell me how facebook login feature works?

How do I get user Info to use in my app? How do I move the view to my actual app?

It would be of great help if I could see an actual working code.. I've been googling and reading documents for almost a week now but I can't figure out how to add log in feature.

Comment: You forgot the opening part of your element in your `render` return value, BTW.